# Looking for a better way to map through array of objects and return specific keys, where ids match

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here is the code i wrote that does work, just looking for a better javascript way.

```js
districts
.map(e => {
  if (e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId) {
    return e.name;
  }
  return undefined;
})
.filter(e => e)[0]
```

where the districts `element.districtId === givenDistrictValueId`
return that element.name

1. can i do this without a filter?
   looking for response = "Some Districts Name"
2. and possibly a slightly different question
   looking for responses = ["Some Districts Name1","Some Districts Name2"]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're filtering then getting the 0th element, you can just use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
districts.find(e => e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId).name
```

Or, null-safe:

```js
districts.find(e => e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId)?.name
```

Or, with compatibility for older js:

```js
(districts.find(e => e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId) || {}).name
```

If you're looking for all the elements and not just the first, one option would be to use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
districts.flatMap(e => e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId ? [e.name] : [])
```

Note that `flatMap` is relatively new, [and is only supported for the major browsers in versions past ~2019](https://caniuse.com/?search=flatmap).

For older support, you could use a `flatMap` polyglot, or try your hand at [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), although this is arguably less readable than `.filter(e => e)`:

```js
districts.reduce((a, e) => {
    if (e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId) {
        a.push(e.name);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: how would you modify to get back multiple instances where ids matched?

Comment: @DarkAdvent I've edited something into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the title of the question "Looking for a better way to map through array of objects and return specific keys, where ids match" is different from what the code is doing, which is to find the *first* element that matches the condition.  If it is the first element, then you'd use `find`. But if it is to find all the elements, then:

My solution would be like @Nick's:

```
results = districts
            .filter(e => (e.districtId === givenDistrictValueId))
            .map(e => e.name);
```

and I would like to add: just like in real life, if you have 100 items and you would find out 3 or 16 particular ones and then find their prices or serial numbers, you'd first filter the items out, and then get their serial numbers.  If you create 100 empty box and put a serial number in it or `undefined` or `null` or `""` in it, you'd be creating the 100 boxes one more time. And it is a bit weird.  If it is a million or two million boxes, it matters more.

There is also one catch: if some item happen to have an empty serial number (a string), then the solution would get one less item in the results if you map first and then filter, because empty string is also falsy. If you filter first and then map, you'd correctly get the empty string.